# ActiveModel validation, change `errors` method name as it clashes with my attribute's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

My model has an attribute named `errors`, it clashes with `ActiveModel::Validations.errors`

Is there any way to customize that method name?

Basically, ActiveModel is messing with my domain.

Edit: It's a model, currently I use it as external service JSON response validator. And they had errors field there.

Comment: It would likely be much easier to rename your field.

Comment: possible, but as @sevenseacat said, it will end up with a very over-engineered solution..

Comment: yeah, mundane. I'll override the field name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to customize that method name?

You shouldn't do that! Instead you should *rename your table column*

```
# db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxx_fix_column_name.rb
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :table_name, :errors, :new_column
  end

  def self.down
    # rename back if you need or do something else or do nothing
  end
end
```